# Socket.io - server down handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to write simple app that serves data using socket.io and node.js on server side. I would like to inform user if server is down (e.g. server serves webpage to the client and before any refresh server is halted). For now it results in browser giving following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1409325689935-6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I wasn't able to catch that event using socket.on('error'(...)) event and I would like to display some message as long as client fails to connect to server. Any ideas would be appreciated :) Code initializing socket is provided below:

```
socket = io.connect(document.domain, {
    'sync disconnect on unload' : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just check if the server serves you the .js file by doing something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" onload="loaded()" src="get_socket.js"></script>

function loaded(){

//this will only execute if the server is up

}
```

Comment: I would like to intercept provided error so that client console window will be free of any errors - using mentioned solution won't prevent them from showing, however - thanks for replying so fast :)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used this following code for not only `socket.io` but any `.js` you wish to load, execute, or both. Please forgive me as I have long forgotten where I originally got this from, most likely this very website.

Please note that I have only tailored the `loadAndExecute` function to handle inability to load your file, via callback.

```
var load,execute,loadAndExecute;
load=function(a,b,c){var d;d=document.createElement("script"),d.setAttribute("src",a),b!=null&&d.addEventListener("load",b),c!=null&&d.addEventListener("error",c),document.body.appendChild(d);return d},
execute=function(a){var b,c;typeof a=="function"?b="("+a+")();":b=a,c=document.createElement("script"),c.textContent=b,document.body.appendChild(c);return c},
loadAndExecute=function(a,b,c){return load(a,function(){return execute(b)},function(){return c();})};
```

Use as such:

```
loadAndExecute("domain.com:80/socket.io/socket.io.js", function() {
    //it loaded, put main code here
},
function(){
    //failed to load, put error display code here
});
```

Hopefully this can help someone like it helped me so many times.